How do I get a ContentView to display a bound value
I have a ContentView called CountBubble:
    <ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                 x:Class="CleanApp.ContentViews.CountBubble"
                 BindingContext="{Binding Source={RelativeSource Self}}">
        <Border
            StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 5,5,5,5"
            StrokeThickness="1"
            BackgroundColor="LightGray"
            Opacity=".65"
            HeightRequest="20">
            <Label 
                x:Name="CountText"
                Text="{Binding Count}"
                FontSize="12"
                HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                Padding="0"/>
        </Border>
    </ContentView>

    public partial class CountBubble : ContentView
    {
        public static readonly BindableProperty CountProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create("Count", typeof(Int32), typeof(CountBubble), 0, BindingMode.TwoWay, propertyChanged: OnCountPropertyChanged);
    
        private static void OnCountPropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldvalue, object newvalue)
        {
            var countBubble = (CountBubble)bindable;
            countBubble.CountText.Text = newvalue.ToString() ?? "0";
        }
    
        public Int32 Count 
        {
            get => (Int32)GetValue(CountProperty);
            set => SetValue(CountProperty, value);
        }
        public CountBubble()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }

I am consuming it like this:
    <Label x:Name="Title"
           Text="{Binding MenuItem.Count}"
           Grid.Column="2"
           VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
    <contentViews:CountBubble
        x:Name="CountBubble"
        Grid.Column="4"             
        Count="{Binding MenuItem.Count}" />

The correct number is displayed in the Title field but only 0 is displayed in the CountBubble.

If I change the CountBubble to define the Count like this:
    <contentViews:CountBubble
        x:Name="CountBubble"
        Grid.Column="4"             
        Count="4" />

The CountBubble displays with the 4.
When CountBubble.Count is set to a binding (Count="{Binding MenuItem.Count}") breakpoints on the setter and OnCountPropertyChanged are never hit.

you need to set a BindingContext, or specify a source value in the binding expression

countBubble.CountText.Text = newvalue.ToString() ?? "0"; this breaks the Binding, remove x:Name="CountBubble" to work safely and try again.

I set the BindingContect in the xaml - BindingContext="{Binding Source={RelativeSource Self}}">

@MustafaMutasim - do I need a PropertyChanged event?  I added one because it didn't work without it.  But the coed is never executed when Count is bound to - Count="{Binding MenuItem.Count}"

You can check this document about using the Relative bindings.

If you want to set the BindingContext for ContentView, you may try x:reference in official doc,
<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             ...
             x:Name="this"
             >
    <Border BindingContext="{x:Reference this}"
            StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 5,5,5,5"
            ...>
        <Label 
                x:Name="CountText"
                Text="{Binding Count}"
                FontSize="12"
                HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                Padding="0"/>
    </Border>

Hope it helps!

I did not notice that, there is an issue with BindableProperty and still Open.
I usualy bind my CustomControls to ViewModel

This workaround tested and works as expected
Replace:
<ContentView ...
             BindingContext="{Binding Source={RelativeSource Self}}">

With:
<ContentView ...
             BindingContext="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:CountBubble}}}">


Replace:
<contentViews:CountBubble x:Name="CountBubble" Grid.Column="4" 
              Count="{Binding MenuItem.Count}" />

With:
<contentViews:CountBubble x:Name="CountBubble" Grid.Column="4"             
              Count="{Binding MenuItem.Count, Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ViewModels:MyViewModels}}}" />

Change ViewModels:MyViewModels as yours namespace:Class

When I made the first replace I got the CountBubble with no number inside it.  When I made the second replace I got an error.  My work around is to remove the binding and set the value in the code behind.  What is the number of the issue you mentioned?

Post your ContentPage or else, which you are using contentViews:CountBubble
